# Python - Inverting a .tif binary image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, google-colaboratory, tiff

I'm using Google Colab with a Jupyter Notebook 3.

I need to invert a .tif binary image, making it's ones into zeros and it's zeros into ones.

How can i do that? (i still need to keep the images as .tif)

**Edit:** I think that my images are being read as if they're completely made of 0. Is there a way of properly reading the images?

**Edit 2:** Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cVqE6DpU_8AhShzX9_MvJpdlTBEAsMMT

**Edit 3:** It's made of 0 and 1's, when I try to vizualize it on QGis it shows perfectly.
Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import imageio

image = imageio.imread("path")

for i in range(0, len(image)):
  for x in range(0, len(image)):
    if image[i,x] == 0:
      image[i,x] = 1
    elif image[i,x] == 1:
      image[i,x] = 0

imageio.imwrite("path", image)
```

Comment: If you share a link to your image, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've edited my question with the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use the package `imageio`

Read the image using the function `imread`

Invert the `ndarray`

Save image usinf `imwrite`

https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it work, i think that my images are being read as if they're completely made of 0. Is there a way of properly reading the images?

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be using `imageio`, you can try:

```
import imageio
import numpy as np                                                                          

# Load image
image = imageio.imread("mask.tif")                                                         

# Change 1s to 0s and 0s to 1s
image = 1 - image                                                                           

# Save result
imageio.imwrite("result.tif", image)
```

Note that you should try and avoid `for` loops with Python image processing as they are terribly slow and inefficient. As you are using `imageio`, your image is already a Numpy array, so you can do the whole inversion as a simple piece of vectorised maths without loops and without `if` statements - which are also slow.

---

If you use PIL/Pillow, you can convert 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open image
im = Image.open('mask.tif') 

# Invert
result = im.point(lambda i: 1-i) 

# Save
result.save('result.tif')
```

[image]

---

Regarding your image... it has a single channel of 8-bit data. 60% of the pixels are 0 and 40% are 1. This will look very dark if you display it, because 0 is black and 255 is white, so your image is black and 99.5% black rather than black and white.

Comment: This worked just fine on my machine, Thank you!

I'm not sure why, but it doesn't work on Google Colab.